# How can Minizinc be used to solve a weighted constraint satisfaction problem_?

Tags: algorithm, constraint-programming, weighted, minimization, minizinc

Given a [weighted constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_constraint_satisfaction_problem) `(X, C, k)` where `X` is a set of variables, `C` is a set of soft constraints and `k > 0` is an integer or infinity; how can this be translated into a minizinc source file?

Each constraint in `C` is a function from a set of assignments of variables in a subset of `X` to a cost `c <= k`

I think these problems (or a useful subset of them) should be able to be translated into minizinc source code, but I lack the experience in minizinc to know how.

Comment: The word "problem" is not allowed in the title, hence the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

[This paper](http://www.minizinc.org/workshop2011/mzn2011_submission_4.pdf) outlines a method in which this must be done.
There doesn't seem to be an implementation, but neither does it seem too complicated. Good luck!